# curl, wget do not return anything

Tags: linux, networking, wget, curl, troubleshooting

I am trying this `curl -I zomato.com | head -n 1`

and I am not getting any response.

```
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 
0  0    0    0     0   0     0       0   --:-  -:--     0:05:29 --:-   -:--     0
```

Is the site protected by firewalls?

Even `wget` is not working on the site as well. Other sites like `google.com` are returning `200` response as expected.

Comment: works for me `$ curl -I zomato.com | head -n 1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: @mikejonesey Wierd. Can you try `wget https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants/dish-chicken-biryani`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl -I --max-redirs 1 "https://www.zomato.com/" 2>/dev/null  | grep "^location:" | awk '{print $2}'
https://www.zomato.com/some-location-in-mongolia
```

so...

```
$ newURL=$(curl -I --max-redirs 1 "https://www.zomato.com/" 2>/dev/null  | grep "^location:" | awk '{print $2}'| grep -o ".*[a-z]"); curl -I "$newURL" | head -n 1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
HTTP/2 200
```

not sure assisting with scrapping is allowed on this forum, but;

```
wget --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" --header "Host: www.zomato.com" --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" "https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants/biryani"
```

Comment: (perhaps your curl is not following redirects?)

Comment: Can you try `wget https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants/dish-chicken-bi‌​ryani`

Comment: that is a 404 in web browser

Comment: https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants/dish-chicken-biryani or just `https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/`

Comment: see edit, (add some headers to wget)

Comment: The site has tags for `wget`, `scrapy`, `beautifulsoup` etc which are tools for web scraping.

Comment: So, why is it that they are not working on my end?